# Can't relate 2 varchar with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have these 2 tables

```
f_data
(
 id (int, null),
 name(varchar(255), null),
 control (int, null),
)
```

id  name                    control
1255    ,ALMONTE JIMENEZ ADALGISA ,     1131238601
92  ,ENCARNACION  PAMELA ,          1131237483
3376    ,FELIZ LUIS MANUEL ,            1131240995
688 ,HERRAND MARIÑE DIOMEDES ,      1131238666
1887    ,JOSE ALBERTO MATOS ,           1131240215

```
est_data
(
id(int, null),
name(varchar(255), null),
firstname(varchar(255), null),
lastname(varchar(255), null),
)
```

id      name        firstname   lastname
201201255   ,ADALGISA   ,ALMONTE    ,JIMENEZ ,
201200092   ,PAMELA     ,ENCARNACION    , ,
201223376   ,LUIS MANUEL    ,FELIZ      , ,
201200688   ,DIOMEDES   ,HERRAND    ,MARIÑE ,
201201887   ,JOSE ALBERTO   ,MATOS      , ,

**and this SQL code**

```
select *
from est_data 
where  
  CASE 
   WHEN 
    lastname  = ' ' 
   then 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(name))   
   ELSE 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname))   + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(lastname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(name)) 
   END in 
        (Select ltrim(rtrim(name)) From f_data where id = 1887)
```

**The result of this:**

```
CASE 
   WHEN 
    lastname  = ' ' 
   then 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(name))   
   ELSE 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname))   + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(lastname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(name)) 
   END
```

is 'JOSE ALBERTO MATOS'

**and the result of this:**

```
Select ltrim(rtrim(name)) From f_data where id = 1887
```

is 'JOSE ALBERTO MATOS'

But the code returns 0 rows, event when the names are the same. What might be the problem here?

note: we are using SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look very carefully at your data. In `f_data` you have a `name` value of "JOSE ALBERTO MATOS". In `est_data` you have a `name` "JOSE", a `firstname` "ALBERTO", and a `lastname` "MATOS".

Now look at your query on `est_data`. You're combining FIRSTNAME-LASTNAME-NAME, which in this case will be "ALBERTO MATOS JOSE", which does not match the value in `f_data`. You're not ordering the names the same way in both places.

If you don't believe me, just run this simple script to recreate the problem:

```
create table #f_data
(
 id int,
 name varchar(255),
 control int
);

create table #est_data
(
id int,
name varchar(255),
firstname varchar(255),
lastname varchar(255)
);

insert into #f_data(id, name, control) values (1887, 'JOSE ALBERTO MATOS', 1);

insert into #est_data(id, name, firstname, lastname) values (1887, 'JOSE', 'ALBERTO', 'MATOS');

Select ltrim(rtrim(name)) From #f_data where id = 1887;

select CASE 
   WHEN 
    lastname  = ' ' 
   then 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(name))   
   ELSE 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname))   + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(lastname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(name)) 
   END
from #est_data;

select *
from #est_data 
where  
  CASE 
   WHEN 
    lastname  = ' ' 
   then 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(name))   
   ELSE 
    ltrim(rtrim(firstname))   + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(lastname))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(name)) 
   END in 
        (Select ltrim(rtrim(name)) From #f_data where id = 1887);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query:

```
select * from (
   select e.*, 
      CASE 
         WHEN e.lastname  = ' ' 
         THEN ltrim(rtrim(e.firstname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(e.name))
         ELSE ltrim(rtrim(e.firstname))   + ' '+ltrim(rtrim(e.lastname)) + ' ' + ltrim(rtrim(e.name))
      END as wrappedName 
   from est_data e
) where wrappedName = 
        (select ltrim(rtrim(name))) from f_data where id = 1887)
```